# Any examples of using Sinatra with acts_as_audited?

Tags: activerecord, sinatra, acts-as-audited

**background**: I am building a web app using `Sinatra` and `ActiveRecord` and I am keen to take advantage of `acts_as_audited` (as per https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited).  The docs for `acts_as_audited` assume I'll be using `Rails` and so assume I'll use `Rails` to generate the necessary migrations.  I've not found any examples of using `acts_as_audited` with `Sinatra`.

**So my question**: Can someone point me at an example of using `Sinatra` and `ActiveRecord` with `acts_as_audited`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to get this to work using the [Audit.as_user](http://rdoc.info/github/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/master/Audit#as_user-class_method) method. Using this method lets you audit records as if the change were made by the user object you pass in.

Here is a simple example.

```
# This is my User model, I want to audit email address changes to it.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_audited
  # user has :email attribute
  ...
end

# This is what I would call in my Sinatra code.
# user is an instance of my User class
...
Audit.as_user(user) do
  user.audit_comment = "updating email from sinatra"
  user.update_attribute(:email, 'foo@bar.com')
end
...
```

A more complex example...

```
# Now I have a User model and a Comments model and I 
# want to audit when I create a comment from Sinatra
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  acts_as_audited
  ...
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_audited
  # has a :body attribute
  ...
end

# This is what I would call in my Sinatra code.
# Again, user is an instance of my User class
...
Audit.as_user(user) do
  user.comments.create(
    :body => "Body of Comment", 
    :audit_comment => "Creating Comment from Sinatra"
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.  What Migrations would I need to add to my tables to support this?

Comment: Sorry about the delay... for reference, the **audit_comment** is stored in the audits table, so once you have run `rails g acts_as_audited:install` and `rake db:migrate` for **acts_as_audited**, you should be good to go.

To get the migration code that `rails g acts_as_audited:install` makes, take a look at the github repo: https://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/blob/master/lib/generators/acts_as_audited/templates/install.rb

Comment: so I'd need to install rails first I guess.

Comment: My particular Sinatra project is using ActiveRecord to interact with models, and is tied to the same db backend as a Rails application, but you can see the actual model migration code in the git repo I linked above and create the appropriate tables however you choose. Since you said you are using ActiveRecord with your Sinatra app, I assumed you have the ability to run migrations from your app. The migration I reference is just the default migration needed to use acts_as_audited at all, so if you have that table created, then you should be good to go.

Comment: cool.  I will give that a go when I dive back into that project next week.  cheers and thanks.